# Filter list based on multiple criteria with Ramda

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, ramda.js

I have a list of cars, that I want to filter based on a filter object, the cars:

```
const cars = [
    {original: {"make": "audi", "model": "a4"}},
    {original: {"make": "bmw", "model": "m5"}},
    {original: {"make": "mercedes", "model": "s"}},
    {original: {"make": "audi", "model": "a6"}},
];
```

The filter object, that can have multiple criteria for the same property (these should be considered as **OR** filters). Each entry in this dictionary ("make", "model") should be considered as an **AND** filter.

```
const filterObject = {
    "make": {
        filters: [
            {prop: "make", value: "audi"},
            {prop: "make", value: "bmw"}
        ]
    }, 
    "model": {
        filters: [
            {prop: "model", value: "a6"}
        ]
    }
}
```

So in this case I should get back the `audi - a6`.
With ramda I could get this far:

```
filter(
  where({
      make: equals("audi"),
      model: equals("a6")
  }), 
  map(x => x.original, data)
)
```

Which works, but there are a couple of problems:

1. `filterObject` is assembled dynamically, so I don't know beforehand what properties are filtered. I should somehow map the object inside `where`, but I got stuck with the multiple conditions criteria. How to make `where` be aware of multiple predicates for each property?
2. At the end I should get back the original (filtered) array. But the relevant part is hidden inside a property (`original`), so before I start filtering, I map over the array to supply the relevant part to the `where` function, therefore in the end this mapped array is returned.

Maybe `where` is not the right approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R.where expects a an object with a predicate function for each property you wish to test. To pass a tested object needs to satisfy all predicates (and).

To test the current object's `make` lets say "audi` against an array of options (or), you can use R.includes.

So the first step is to create a where object, where each predicate checks the current object's value against an array of values.

```js
const { map, pipe, prop, pluck, includes, flip, where } = R;

const createFilters = map(pipe(
  prop('filters'),
  pluck('value'),
  flip(includes)
));

const cars = [{"original":{"make":"audi","model":"a4"}},{"original":{"make":"bmw","model":"m5"}},{"original":{"make":"mercedes","model":"s"}},{"original":{"make":"audi","model":"a6"}}];

const filterObject = {"make":{"filters":[{"prop":"make","value":"audi"},{"prop":"make","value":"bmw"}]},"model":{"filters":[{"prop":"model","value":"a6"}]}};

const filters = createFilters(filterObject);

console.log(filters);

console.log(where(filters, {"make":"audi","model":"a4"})) // false
console.log(where(filters, {"make":"audi","model":"a6"})) // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then you when filtering the data, get the object from the `origin`, and use the R.where with the applied filters:

```js
const { map, pipe, prop, pluck, includes, flip, curry, filter, where } = R;

const createFilters = map(pipe(
  prop('filters'),
  pluck('value'),
  flip(includes)
));

const fn = curry((filters, data) => filter(pipe(
  prop('original'),
  where(createFilters(filters)), 
))(data));

const cars = [{"original":{"make":"audi","model":"a4"}},{"original":{"make":"bmw","model":"m5"}},{"original":{"make":"mercedes","model":"s"}},{"original":{"make":"audi","model":"a6"}}];

const filterObject = {"make":{"filters":[{"prop":"make","value":"audi"},{"prop":"make","value":"bmw"}]},"model":{"filters":[{"prop":"model","value":"a6"}]}};

const result = fn(filterObject)(cars);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```